# How do I tell a deferred object what code needs to complete to fire .done() in the promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to roll my own deferred and promise. All of the tutorials that I see "resolve" the deferred in the call back associated with a jquery call. For instance, in this [tutorial](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/06/03/make-your-own-jquery-deferreds-and-promises/), the line `dfd.resolve("Finished fading out!");` seems to bind the deferred object to the animate method. Is that what it means to "resolve" the deferred object? I am [using code](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/) that does not seem to take a function call back like that. How do I wrap this code into a promise?

```
function respondToSearch(){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    //I want promise.done to fire when this has finished. how do I glue this code to the deferred?
    dc.embed.load('http://www.documentcloud.org/search/embed/', {some json}); 
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: What’s `dc.embed.load`? Just jQuery’s `$.fn.load`?

Comment: @minitech it appears so. Or at least I am able to put a call back there which is hugely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function respondToSearch(){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    dc.embed.load('http://www.documentcloud.org/search/embed/', {some json}, function() {
        // This is where you would tell the promise it should be resolved or failed, etc.
        // in which case, the promise's "done" callbacks will be fired
        dfd.resolve();
    }); 

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Edit: this is assuming as OP mentioned, dc.embed.load() is $.fn.load()